# Plot error in slice index, working on python 2.7 not on 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, plot

In python 2.7 this script is working fine, using it in python 3 in Notebook I get an error.

```
for j in range(0,C):
 dataWO=np.loadtxt(filenamesWO[j*pas])
 G2[:,j]=dataWO[:,1]
 tps=dataWO[:,0]
 plt.plot(np.float(j*pas)*0.2+dataWO[:,1]/np.max(dataWO[0:L*4/5,1])*10.,tps,'k')
 plt.plot(np.float(j*pas)*0.2+G[:,j]/np.max(G[0:L*4/5,j])*10.,tps,'r') 
plt.show()
```

### Error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1483534b9049> in <module>
      3         G2[:,j]=dataWO[:,1]
      4         tps=dataWO[:,0]
----> 5         plt.plot(np.float(j*pas)*0.2+dataWO[:,1]/np.max(dataWO[0:L*4/5,1])*10.,tps,'k')
      6         plt.plot(np.float(j*pas)*0.2+G[:,j]/np.max(G[0:L*4/5,j])*10.,tps,'r') 
      7 plt.show()

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s telling you what the error is. You can’t have floats inside a slicing (`G[...]`) expression on arrays. In Python 2, `L*4/5` returns an integer (for integer `L`), while in Python 3 it returns a float. Use `L*4//5` to force integer division.